# Algún ejemplo de autenticación múltiple con Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buen día estimados. Tengo dos tipos de usuarios con diferentes modelos en mi proyecto de Laravel y quisiera saber si alguno sabe como utilizar los $guards que provee Laravel, para tener varios usuarios.

Mis tipos de usuarios son "empresa", "usuario", "administrador".

Si me pudieran dar algún ejemplo lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Los usuarios son eso usuarios, el tipo solo es una propiedad, no deberían ser tablas ni modelos diferentes, esto te dará problemas en las referencias y dolores de cabeza, además de caer en polimorfismo innecesario. Mi recomendación es que manejes los usuarios en una única tabla.

Comment: Y usar solo middlewares para los accesos?